# Skype status showing always online

Tags: skype, sleep

Skype has recently started showing my online status as constantly "online" even after I have been inactive for longer than the configured time period of 5 minutes.  Things that I have tried:

- Reinstalling Skype on all PCs
- Disabling all Skype Extras

I use the same skype account on my desktop, laptop, and Iphone.  Any ideas on why my skype status may be stuck or any other suggestions to help resolve this?

UPDATE: I deleted config.xml from %APPDATA%/gdalgas in an attempt to resolve this which didn't help.

Comment: I also observed this.. Are you getting this on Windows 2008 or Windows 7?

Comment: I am on Windows Vista x64, x86, and IPhone 3.0

Answer (score 12, accepted):

http://how-can-i-how-do-i-how-to.blogspot.com/2010/04/how-to-fix-show-me-as-away-when.html

> Go to Tools/Options and change Show me as away after X minutes to some other value. Like 4 minutes. Save it.
>
> Then go to Tools/Options again and set it to some other value again like 5 minutes. Save it.

Comment: confirmed, this works.. silly, but it works.

Answer (score 2):

Not trying to be a wiseguy, but have you checked your General Settings under tools->options "Show me as 'Away' when I am inactive for" value is set correctly?

Comment: Yes, I have a value set for 5 minutes

Answer (score 2):

If you say it's installed on all those platforms, than it might be you just use either your desktop, laptop or iPhone every 5 mins keeping you "online".

Because all three versions share one account.

Else I would expect a wrong Options setting like JP suggested

Answer (score 0):

A thing to check would be if your computer actually detects the "idle". For example if you have a mouse which is too sensitive (or live in a seismic area), it might be that there is constant activity. Do your other "idle" behaviors trigger correctly ? (screensaver activating, or monitor turning off, or even status from another communicator)